# How can I add DNS mapping to my router?

Tags: dns

I know about the "hosts" file that can map ips to static names. 
But I want to do the same thing inside the router, so I can access this "hosts" file by any computer on that LAN.
I have D LINL router. how can I achive my target?

Answer (score 0):

Your router will normally let you tell it which DNS server to use, but not edit a hosts file.

You could research custom firmware for your specific router:
http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index

Check 
 1. Is your specific router supported 
 2. Does the firmware allow editing the hosts file, and do the instructions on how to do it make sense - before you install the firmware

The dd-wrt site also has a forum where people may be able to help you, or direct you to a different router if this one won't do.